# Cannot access vpc endpoint eventhough have access for all ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

Cannot access endpoints in vpc. Even after giving access to all ec2 apis in IAM role. here is the IAM role -

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
   }
   ]
}
```

Opening  the vpc endpoints in the console gives me an authorization error.

Am trying to build an endpoint between vpc and s3 and add that to route table. 
It is weird that I get this error even after providing full access to ec2 and s3

Comment: You need to provide more info. Give the IAM Role perhaps, maybe it's incorrect.

Comment: You will need to clarify and define both "cannot access" (what happens when you try?) and "endpoint" (what kind of endpoint?)  before any of us can begin to understand this question.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. I created a new IAM user, assigned them your policy (above), went to the VPC management console and successfully created an "Endpoint".

Comment: @john that is what I am wondering still cannot rectify the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS account was registered with a specific region. When removing that, vpc endpoints are accessible

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Feel free to mark your answer as Correct. However, what do you mean by "registered with a specific region"?

Comment: The policy with a condition having the region